# Change Image size from 150*150 to 70*70 in using sql query?

Tags: image, sql-server-2008

I am storing image in SQL server 2008 R2 database in varBinary(max) column named: image1 which is of size 150*150. I have added another column named image2 varBinary(max) and i need to update this column with the same image in image1 but with 70*70 size. Is it possible to do this using sql query.

I have tried to find the query but not getting any clue how to do this. Please let me know if anyone has done this before and how?

Comment: SQL Server is a **database** (to store and retrieve data) - not an image processor... you cannot expect T-SQL to be able to do all sorts of operations like image resizing - that's a job for an **application** written in C# or something like that.

Comment: Yes presently i am doing using C# but i am trying to find a faster way. So just need to know if there is any workaround for that in SQL

Comment: No - SQL is about storing and retrieving data - not about image processing, sorry.

Comment: Why don't you just resize the image as you go - as marc said it's not possible in tsql, but I can't think of a reason to store thumbnails or whatever it is - let's take a look at marc_s avatar - the link is quite large http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b4779212f57ff2e9549ea90a4499c2d7?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG but as you can notice there's a s=32 argument - the size of the picture. You can use the same approach for your solution

Comment: Actually i am trying to display a data on a listview with thumbnail image if the same data comes multiple number of times then every time i need to re-size the image which becomes a costly process for my website on azure.

Comment: @BalrajSingh resize it as you do now but also fill the database with the thumbnail if one does not exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with everyone's points here, but if you really wanted to or had to, you could enable CLR integration on the SQL Server, create an assembly that could resize your image, and then call it from a trigger or proc.  Its not very hard.  Here a page that describes the process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(VS.80).aspx

Basicly to enable CLR on the SQL Server:

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Create a c#  assembly to resize your image:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public class ResizeImageProc
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void ResizeImage(int ImageID, int width, int height)
    {
       //TODO: ResizeImage Code
    }
}
```

Compile the assembly

```
csc /target:library ResizeImageProc.cs
```

Load the assembly in the SQL Server:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY ResizeImageAssembly from 'c:\ResizeImageProc.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

Create the proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ResizeImage AS EXTERNAL NAME ResizeImageAssembly.ResizeImageProc.ResizeImage
```

After that you can call it like a normal proc.  For example:

```
EXEC ResizeImage(1,800,600)
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been said in a few of the comments, SQL is a data storage system and is unable to edit your images.

I suggest that you perform a one-time update on the table using your preferred language (c# etc) fetching each image and resizing it before updating it back into the table.

Then from that point on ensure that any images inserted into the table are resized before they are inserted.

Comment: I agree that this is the best approach, and using a .NET language will allow you to do this fairly easily. Have a look at `System.Drawing`.